# Why conditioning in IIB Mapping Node invalidates the response XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, mapper, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I've been using an `If` condition in IIB Mapping node on request's boolean attribute `Flag` that maps to `messageA` attribute in response. Assignment is done in case `Flag` evaluates as `true`.

There is another `For Each` which performs deep copy of a list and also assigns some value to the same variable `messageA`, if `Flag` is evaluated as `false`.

Below is the Mapper Logic:

[image: ESQL Mapper]

The above logic yields valid XML in case `Flag` is `false`, but in case of `true` it assigns the value successfully, however invalidates the response as defined in the XSD, by appending `messageA` attribute as the last child of response XML.

How can the second scenario be treated? Considering no custom ESQL logic in the latter nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create tag in the specified location, when you have no valid value in mapper and you override it through ESQL and it is not created where you are expecting.

to avoid this, use mappers built in Create function.

this will reserve the space for your element, and when ever you populate its value this would be on the expected position and schema would be validated as well